# how to compare and call function in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm studying javascript and I'm making a form where it will ask for a start address and a destination address. What I want to do - but cant figure out - is how i can get javascript to compare the two values if my input box and if it exist on the function it will show a message, but if it doesn't exist it will still loop until it finds the value and shows the message or shows an error if it really doesn't have anything.

based on this HTML form:

```
<div id="panel">
<form>
<input type="text" placeholder="Start Address" id="start" >

<input type="text" placeholder="Destination Address" id="end">

<input type="button" value="Get Direction"  id="SubmitBtn" onclick="printme()" >


</form>
</div>
<div id="infopanel">
</div>


    function printme(){

       var start = document.getElementById("start").value;
   var end = document.getElementById("end").value;
   var  point1="point1";
       var  point2="point2";
       var  point3"point3";

if (start==point1&&end==point2){
    document.getElementById("infopanel").innerHTML="point1 to point2 just ride a taxi";
    }
else if (start==point1&&end==point3){
    document.getElementById("infopanel").innerHTML="point1 to point3 just ride a bus";
}
    else document.getElementById("infopanel").innerHTML="no route found we will update    you       ";
}
```

example : if start is equal to point1 and end is equal to point2  show "just ride a cab" else if start is equal point 1 and end is point3 show "just ride a bus" else show "no route found we will update you "

Comment: Sooooooo... what have you tried? Where is your Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

```
function printme() {
    var start = document.getElementById('start').value;
    var end = document.getElementById('end').value;

    if (start !== end) {
        alert("can't go there!");
    } else {
        alert("you must ride a " + start.split(' ')[0]); // appends the first word entered into the input
    }
}
```

Comment: but if the value of start is malaysia and end is australia instead of you must ride a plain it will say "cant go there becasue (start !== end). right?

Comment: not an app but yes to find the way to travel between to locations for educational purposes :) thanks for the offer

Comment: I was just being sarcastic :) (the code required to do what you want is probably larger than a single SO answer). Still if you code it and have any specific questions later on I'll be more than happy to help